# why is this wrong in my sql? it says check version

Tags: mysql

the error says that i have to check the version of mysql but i checked and it is right..

```
    CREATE TABLE Persons (
    person_id int,
    first_name varchar(20),
    last_name varchar(20),
    address varchar(20),
    city varchar(20)
);


INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (1, "keene", "basence", "escarlata", "makati");
INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (2, "kyle", "basence", "escarlata", "makati");
INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (3, "kieffer", "basence", "escarlata", "makati");

SELECT * FROM Persons;

DELETE FROM Persons WHERE person_id = 1;

UPDATE Persons SET address = "comembo" WHERE person_id = 1;

SELECT person_id, first_name FROM Persons GROUP BY person_id DESC; -- this is the wrong one
```

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals, not double quotes.

Comment: Also, always include the column values when inserting. It prevents a tons of silent errors.

Comment: Instead of `GROUP BY` maybe you meant `ORDER BY`.

Comment: what i want is that them group by descending like 1, 2 ,3 and only showing the person_id and first_name, the last code is i want to fix

Comment: that's the one i was supposed to use ORDER BY.. thank you very much for the help

Comment: 'Prior to MySQL 8.0.13, MySQL supported a nonstandard syntax extension that permitted explicit ASC or DESC designators for GROUP BY columns'  - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html WHAT version of mysql are you on.

Comment: @EdwinBasa Since you found the answer, please post it as an answer. Something like "I was supposed to use ORDER BY instead of GROUP BY in the last query."

Comment: i'm using the newest MySQL and it fix now... i was supposed to used ORDER BY and thank for your help everyone.

Comment: I was supposed to use ORDER BY instead of GROUP BY in the last query.